# EJB Timer IllegalArgumentException

Tags: ejb, weblogic, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

I have an EJB3.0 timer which runs great.During application deployment i see this error in my WL logs,

```
 An exception occurred while registering the MBean null.java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Registered more than one instance with the same objectName : com.bea:ServerRuntime=admin,Name=weblogic.ejb.timer"
```

And during undeployment this

```
 An unexpected error was encountered while attempting to remove any EJB Timers from the persistent store for the EJB 'TimerBean(Application: )
```

I don't use persistence store mechanism.I trigger the timer with servlet context.

We use WL 10.3.1,How can i overcome/catch this exception so,that it wouldn't be displayed during build process.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The WLS ejb timers are persisted to a default store. The error messages seem to be related to it. Its likely that the ejb timer from a previous deployment is interfering. Does a server restart resolve this issue? You may want to try your app on WLS 10.3.4 to see if the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Hi,this error is thrown during undeploy and deploy only,once the application is running,I don't see this issue.We can't migrate to WL 10.3.4 just to overcome this but i have read this version of WL should behave different.One thing i might need to know is "how can I detect the timer interference"?